# Dynamic Values in Function

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a simple PHP script that renders events on a calendar.  Normally, the function is called like this:

```
$calendar->standard('today')
          ->standard('prev-next')
          ->attach($event1)
          ->attach($event2)
          ->attach($event3);
```

However, the number of events is dynamic so I need to build this call dynamically.  I have something like this:

```
while ($i > 0)
{
    $calendarAttach .= '->attach($event'.$i.')';
    $i--;
}
```

However, when I try to call the calendar function like below, I get an error that the object cannot be converted to a string:

```
$calendar->standard('today')
      ->standard('prev-next')
          .$calendarAttach;
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but would appreciate any help!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use simple `foreach` loop:

```
$calendar->standard('today')
      ->standard('prev-next');
foreach($events as $event) {
    $calendar->attach($event);
}
```

Or `while` loop like in your code:

```
while ($i > 0)
{
    $calendar->attach(${'event'.$i});
    $i--;
}
```